# Wedge contour parameterisation with $\oint{e^{i\lambda z^p}\, dz}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, contour-integration, gamma-function

I was trying to compute the 3rd integral, marked $z=re^{i\frac{\pi}{2p}}$ for $\oint{e^{i\lambda z^p}\, dz}$. I started with $z=re^{i\frac{\pi}{2p}}$ followed by $t=\lambda r^p$ :

$$\begin{align}\int_{\Gamma}{e^{i\lambda z^p}\, dz}&=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2p}}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-\lambda r^p}\, dr}\\&=p\lambda^{1/p}e^{i\frac{\pi}{2p}}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-t}\, t^{1-1/p}\, dt}\\&=p\lambda^{1/p}e^{i\frac{\pi}{2p}}\Gamma\left(2-\frac{1}{p}\right)\end{align}$$

Trying with some numbers like $\lambda=1$ and $p=2$ seem like the solution is ok. The answer which [this](https://www.phys.uconn.edu/%7Erozman/Courses/P2400_17S/downloads/stationary-phase.pdf) (page 2/3) document gives is $$e^{i\frac{\pi}{2p}}\lambda^{-1/p}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{p}+1\right)$$

Are these really the same result or was the $\lambda=1$ and $p=2$ case just a coincidence?

[image: contour]

Comment: Isn't your function holomorphic? If yes, the loop integral should be zero and used to compute the integral on $[0,\infty]$?

Comment: @JulesBesson yes this is the end goal, but I'm concerned I made a mistake since my answer is different to the one given on the document. Maybe the gamma function can be rewritten but I'm not sure why the sign of the exponent of $\lambda$ is different for example.

Comment: You have an error in your change of variables. It should be $dr = d[(t/\lambda)^{1/p}] = t^{1/p-1}/(p\lambda^{1/p}) dt$.

Comment: Ok may I suggest you replace $\oint$ by $\int_\Gamma$ or something else? $\oint$ is the circular integral

Comment: fixed @JulesBesson

Comment: I meant the one in your computation

Comment: should be good now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to want is the computation of
$$\int_0^\infty e^{i\lambda x^p} dx$$

For this you consider the path $\Gamma(R)$ which is the concatenation of the paths $\Gamma_1(R)$ on the real line, $\Gamma_2 (R)$ the arc part, and $\Gamma_3 (R)$ the line with the angle. You have $\int_{\Gamma_2(R)} e^{i \lambda z^p} \to 0$ when $R \to \infty$ which gives you:

$$A =\int_0^\infty e^{i\lambda x^p} dx = -\int_{\Gamma_3(\infty)} e^{i\lambda z^p}  = \int_0^\infty \gamma'(x) e^{i\lambda \gamma(x)^p} dx
$$
with $\gamma(x) = xe^{i\frac{\pi}{2p}}$

So
$$A = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2p}} \int_0^\infty e^{i^2\lambda x^p} dx = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2p}} \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x^p} dx $$
Take now $u = \lambda x^p$, i.e. $x = \lambda^{-1/p} u^{1/p}$ so $dx = \lambda^{-1/p} u^{1/p -1}\frac{du}{p}$ **(this is where you made a mistake)** You get
$$A  = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2p}}\frac{\lambda^{-1/p}}{p} \int_0^\infty u^{1/p -1}e^{-u} du  = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2p}}\frac{\lambda^{-1/p}}{p} \Gamma(1/p)$$

But $x \Gamma(x) = \Gamma(x+1)$ so
$$A = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2p}}\lambda^{-1/p} \Gamma(1+ 1/p)$$